# Moving the cursor to a hyperlink with Python

Tags: python, winapi

I am trying to do some automation using the win32api. I want to point the cursor over some specifc links on a webpage. Am able to scroll a page with the below call. Is there a way to scroll the page, until the cursor is on a hyperlink (scroll until the cursor changes to a hand-shaped cursor)

```py
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL, 0, 0, off, 0)
```

Comment: Would it not be better to parse the html?

Comment: yes, that would be easier, but, i dont want to open the links programatically. trying to simulate manual clicking links on the browser

Comment: What are you actually trying to do. Usually faking input is the last resort.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the handle of the current cursor through GetCursorInfo() in win32 api, and then compare with the result from LoadCursor + IDC_HAND to achieve the effect you want.
Here is the code you can refer:

```
import win32api
import win32con
import win32gui
import time
while True:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL, 0, 0, -1)   
    ci = win32gui.GetCursorInfo()  #Get the handle of the current cursor
    if(ci[0] == 0):
        print("cursor disappear")
        continue
    hc = win32gui.LoadCursor(0,win32con.IDC_HAND)  #Get the handle of cursor you need
    if(ci[1] == hc):
        print("now is the hand-shaped cursor")
```

Also, if you need a hyperlink to specify the content, you can achieve it by parsing the html source code of the web page. You can refer to the following simple example:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen('https://stackoverflow.com/')
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
t1 = bsObj.find_all('a')
for t2 in t1:
    t3 = t2.get('href')
    print(t3)
```

Comment: Hi,if this answer did help to you, please feel free to mark it to help people with the same issue, and let me know if you have any problem.